# Why would the oil rise in this situation?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, potential, dielectric, inductance

Given:

> Two long coaxial cylindrical metal tubes (inner radius a, outer radius b)
>   stand vertically in a tank of dielectric oil (susceptibility χe, mass density
>   ρ). The inner one is maintained at potential V , and the outer one is
>   grounded (see figure). To what height (h) does the oil rise, in the space
>   between the tubes?

Why would the oil rise in the first place? I assumed the oil was placed in there, everything was set up, and only *then* did the inner tube get set to a specific potential. But I may be wrong.

**Update:** so it looks like the force that pushes the oil up is the electric force. I assume this comes from the battery.

Comment: What are the inner and outer radii of the two coaxial metal tubes (one is inside the other) ? Which tube hasthe  inner radius a and the outer radius b?

Comment: One is inside the other. The inner tube has radius a and the outer one has radius b.

Comment: This is a standard "force on a dielectric in a capacitor" type problem dealt with by many authors eg [Physics Pages][1].


  [1]: http://www.physicspages.com/2012/11/12/force-on-a-dielectric/

Answer (score 1):

I assume that the outer tube has the inner radius $b$ and the inner tube has the outer radius $a$. When you apply a voltage $V$ between the tubes, the additional capacitance of the height $h$ of the tube filled with the liquid dielectric with susceptibility $\chi_e$, giving the relative permittivity $\epsilon =1+\chi_e$, is $$C=\frac{2\pi\epsilon_0\chi_e h}{\ln{(b/a)}}$$ Thus the energy of this *additional* capacitance $C$ is $$W=\frac{CV^2}{2}=\frac{\pi\epsilon_0\chi_e h V^2}{\ln{(b/a)}}$$ This energy $W$ corresponds to the work done by the battery to lift the liquid dielectric to height $h$. Thus the battery force on the liquid dielectric corresponding to a change in h is $$F_B=\frac{dW}{dh}=\frac{\pi\epsilon_0\chi_e V^2}{\ln{(b/a)}}$$ On the other hand, the counteracting hydrostatic pressure force is $$F_H=A\rho gh=\pi (b^2-a^2)\rho gh$$ where $A$ is the area of the lifted liquid between the tubes. This force increases with h. Thus the liquid rises upon application of the voltage $V$ to a height $h$ where $F_B=F_H$. This yields the height $h$ of the liquid $$h=\frac{\epsilon_0\chi_e V^2}{(b^2-a^2)\rho g\ln{(b/a)}}$$

Comment: That answer fails the most obvious check of setting $\epsilon=1$, where the height should clearly be zero since the dielectric is no different from vacuum.

Comment: @Suzu Hirose - Thanks. I posted it too fast. I will find and correct the error.

Comment: @Suzu Hirose. Error corrected. The *additional* capacitance C due to $h$ is proportional to $\chi_e$ not to the  total relative $\epsilon=1+\chi_e$.